# $.each() loop + for loop used with getJSON()

Tags: jquery, json

if i run this the all `$.getjson` run simultaneously
i want to wait the first getjson to finish then the next
hope you can help me thanks in advance

```
//start loop

param.forEach(item, function () {

    $.getJSON(item, function (data) {

        $.each(data, function (i, val) {

            //store data in html

            $('#tabledata tbody').append(html);
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: try to get your data in single getJson call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the callback function

http://www.impressivewebs.com/callback-functions-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
function request(array) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return;
    }
    var item = array.shift();
    $.getJSON(item, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (i, html) {
            $('#tabledata tbody').append(html);
        });
        request(array);
    });
}
request(item)
```

Comment: thanks for reply but i want is for example i have a 20 days of records and each day have 10 records and i want to display it one by one per day. so its means 20 getjson run simultaneously i want it one by one. thanks again